# loop through two arrays with different sizes and find equal items

Tags: php

I have two arrays with different sizes and I want to do some action when two items are equal.

my arrays may look like this

```
array_1 = { 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value3' }
array_2 = { 'key2' => 'value2' }
```

in the example above I want to perform an action when key2 from array_1 and key2 from array_2 are found.

Currently I am using 2 foreach loops to do this. Something like this:

```
    foreach ($block->getSettingsNoDefaults() as $baseKey => $value) {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($blockData->settings as $saveKey => $value) {
            if($baseKey == $saveKey) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!$found) {
            $block->removeSetting($baseKey);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to use some other more elegant way to do this insead of two foreach loops to compare all values from one array to all values from second array and then act if they match?

I thought first of using php's array_map("myfunction",$array_1 ,$array_2) to do this but it does not seem like right function in my case, since it will loop through both arrays and only compare elements that are at the same index.

Is there any other function that I can use in my case so I can make my code more elagant then using multiple forloops.

Comment: So are you specifically trying to find out if two objects share the same key, or would simply comparing the lengths of the two objects suffice?

Comment: if the share same keys and act on it if they do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array_key_exists and one foreach loop.

**Solution**

```
$array_1 = [ 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value3' ];
$array_2 = [ 'key2' => 'value2' ];
foreach($array_2 as $key => $item){
   if(array_key_exists($key, $array_1)){
       echo "Match found.";
   }
}
```

**Updated Answer** I found that you can use array_intersect_key($a1,$a2) instead

```
$array_1 = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value3');
$array_2 = array('key2' => 'value2' );
$result = array_intersect_key($array_1,$array_2);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: nice, that will shave off one foreach, not bad! :)